# Set Size of Rectangle to image size

Tags: wpf, size, opacitymask

i'm using this, to show icons that can change their color

```
<Rectangle Width="100"
           Height="100"
           Fill="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush">
   <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
      <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource={x:Static ImageResources.MyImage}"/>
   </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

The thing is, that not every Image looks good in 100x100 and if I do not fill these values, nothing is shown. What I wanted to achieve is, that the rectangle automatically takes the needed size of the Image, same as if I would use

```
<Image Source="{x:Static ImageResources.MyImage}"/>
```

Any Idea how to achieve this? I already tried to give the ImageBrush a name and reference the size from the rectangle, this doesn't work.

As a workaround I placed an Image at the same position with Visibility=Hidden and get the actualHeight and actualWidth for the Rectangle from there, but that's not an acceptable solution. Any hints welcome.

Comment: If i understand correct then your purpose is to display image in rectangle only , Am i correct ?

Comment: @GaurangDave yes, I guess so

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the Rectangle's Width and Height:

```
<Rectangle Fill="{DynamicResource WhiteBrush"
           Width="{Binding Width, Source={x:Static ImageResources.MyImage}}"
           Height="{Binding Height, Source={x:Static ImageResources.MyImage}}">
    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Static ImageResources.MyImage}"/>
    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: ah, I didn't know you can bind to properties of a static image, nice. The only thing is, that this sets the image to its original size. I surrounded it with a viewbox to scale it to a better size then. Thank you

Comment: is it possible to set the Source to a Image gathered from a converter? Something like Width="{Binding Width, Source={Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource StatusToImageConverter}}}"

Comment: i also did not see a reason why this wouldn't work. But I tried it and the Image disappeared, like I don't set a width or height at all

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read that XAML in your comment carefully enough. A Binding inside a Binding won't work. You could perhaps have Binding Converter that returns different properties like Width or Height of the BitmapSource, depending on the value of the ConverterParameter property.